# Get all media from a certain chat or group with Telethon

Tags: python, telethon

I faced the problem that I can't retrieve all media messages from a certain group or a chat in Telegram. Opened the documentation and still can't find something useful. My code gets only the profile photo of the group. How do I get all media messages?

```
client = TelegramClient('session_name', app_id, api_hash)
client.start(phone=79773747931)
with TelegramClient('my', app_id, api_hash) as client:
    all_photos = client.iter_profile_photos('https://t.me/+g7aEU_5qw6tjMmQ9')
    for photo in all_photos:    
        client.download_media(photo)
```

Answer (score 1):

[`iter_messages`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.iter_messages) has `filter` , pass it any of [MessagesFilter](https://tl.telethon.dev/types/messages_filter.html)

```py
from telethon.tl.types import InputMessagesFilterPhotos
    ...
    all_photos = client.iter_messages(
  chat, filter=InputMessagesFilterPhotos
)
    for photo in all_photos:
        client.download_media(photo)
```